# Landing pages urls

Tags: url, xslt, razor, umbraco

I have a website where I need the images to link to several landing pages. All the links are different for all the pages, but they are all using the same template.

I want to write a macro (XSLT, RAZOR, CSHTML) to be able to put the correct link for the correct image based on the page user is on. I want to read an Excel file or any other file to be able to do this.

Please advise. If there is any other better solution please let me know as I am not aware of XSLT's capabilities as I am totally new to umbraco, CSHTML, XSLT, XML, etc.

Kind Regards, SA

Comment: You may have to rewrite the question a little - it doesn't make much sense. Also, give an example we might be able to work with.

Comment: I have a text page template, where i am inserting an umbraco field "CTA".  I want to link this CTA image to a landing page.  Now, there are several pages that uses this text page template and hence the CTA image.  Now, the problem that there are different landing page URLs for different pages.  The problem is how can i use the same template with same image but linking the <a href> tag to different landing pages.  My strategy was to write a macro or something that would return back the link to the template based on page address i.e. for domain/page1 it would go to page.html and for domain/page2

Comment: Ok, so it actually has nothing to do with images or templates. You just want to output a link URL based upon the page being displayed?

Comment: Yes, you are right in saying that. my initial idea was to read a file (excel, xml etc) then based on domain file i will link to the URL. Please advise, if this is possible or there is a better way ? Regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to include a property on the pages. This property would allow you to specify the URL that the macro can then pick up on.

Comment: this is like lot of manual work if i do like that as there are about 100s of URL, that is why i wanted to automate this. Regards

Comment: Sorry, are there 100s of pages which would need a property adding or are there 100s of URLs which the pages could potentially use? How many landing pages are there? Is there a pattern to tie the landing page to a CMS page? E.g. Could you apply a URL property to a root page that all descendant pages underneath could inherit?

Comment: No, there is no pattern, there are 100 random URLs. The template is one. the pages that use the template are about 30-40. The idea is to minimize the work by reading the excel sheet, matching the page address (url) and linking the image within that page to the relevant URL (one of 100). Hope my question makes sense. Regards, Sarah

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. Feel free to email me directly (you can Google me). I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help. I have managed to get a javascript that does the job. However, i cannot seem to link and read the file from my server. Below is the code please check and advise.Regards.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var hn = window.location;
 document.write(hn);
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","~/images/cd_catalog.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{

 document.write("<tr><td>");
 if(((x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == "One night        only")||((x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) ==    "Bees Gees"))
{ document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 document.write("</td><td>");
 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 document.write("</td></tr>");
 }
}

 document.write("</table>");

 </script>
```

Please note that the spaces etc are due to formatting on the forum,